# How to add scores like 'A','B','C' with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

Hello I want to ask something

how to add scores like A B C D with mysql QUERY

```
SELECT dcm_peserta.nm1, COUNT(siswa.nis) as jml, ROUND(dcm_peserta.nm1 / COUNT(dcm_peserta.nis) * 100) as percent

        /* add SELECT for scoring here */
FROM dcm_peserta, siswa
WHERE siswa.id_kelas = dcm_peserta.id_kelas AND dcm_peserta.id_kelas = '65'
GROUP BY dcm_peserta.nis
```

Like if *percent = 0* the score A, if *percent = 1 until 20* score B

any Idea?

Comment: you can use CASE [Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *have to do it in the query*, use `CASE`:

Note the cases are processed from the top down in the same way an `if...elseif` structure would be, so you do not need to be explicit about the range (i.e. I have done `>80` after the `=100`, so the `'F'` will only be selected if the `=100` does not pass. That is, `>80` and `<> 100`.)

```
SELECT ...
    CASE WHEN ROUND(dcm_peserta.nm1 / COUNT(dcm_peserta.nis) * 100) = 100 THEN 'G'
         WHEN ROUND(dcm_peserta.nm1 / COUNT(dcm_peserta.nis) * 100) > 80 THEN 'F'
         WHEN ROUND(dcm_peserta.nm1 / COUNT(dcm_peserta.nis) * 100) > 60 THEN 'E'
         WHEN ROUND(dcm_peserta.nm1 / COUNT(dcm_peserta.nis) * 100) > 40 THEN 'D'
         WHEN ROUND(dcm_peserta.nm1 / COUNT(dcm_peserta.nis) * 100) > 20 THEN 'C'
         WHEN ROUND(dcm_peserta.nm1 / COUNT(dcm_peserta.nis) * 100) > 0 THEN 'B'
         ELSE 'A'
    END AS score
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you I like to use this one

Answer (score 3):

Just use a dictionary to lookup the grades when you do it in `php`:

```
$grades = array ( -1=>'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E','F' );

for ($percentage=0; $percentage<=100; $percentage++) {
  $grade = $grades[floor(($percentage-1)/20)];
  echo sprintf("%s%% => %s\n", $percentage, $grade);
}
```

Comment: I think you may need to do a special case for `A` just being 0 and `B` 1 and up.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Indeed, you are right, I fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, outstanding answer :-)